# About Boundary Points of $R$ themselves not belonging to $R$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am quoting *Thomas' Calculus $12$th edition, section $14.1$, Page $749$*.

> A point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is a **boundary point** of $R$ if every disk centred at $(x_{0},y_{0})$ contains points that lie outside of $R$ as well points that lie in $R$. (The boundary point itself need not belong to $R$.)

What I really don't understand here is that, why as per the definition, the boundary point need not belong to $R$. It is after all a boundary point of $R$. It would be great to get some clarification on this. Thanks.

Comment: I believe $R$ is open set, then boundary points do not belong to $R$. If $R$ is closed set, then boundary points belong to $R$.

Comment: $0$ is a boundary point of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, if $R=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x>0\}$, then $(0,0)$ is a boundary point of $R$ (every ball centered at $(0,0)$ contains points from $R$ and points from $\Bbb R^2\setminus R$), but $(0,0)\notin R$.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.